# SwiftUI trigger function when notification is sent?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, notifications

I currently have a system that can send notifications to the phone in my app. I would like to perform a function every time that notification is sent? Any help is appreciated.

My current code for creating a notification.

```
    static func addNotification(sub: SubscriptionItem){
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    let addRequest = {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "\(sub.name)"
        content.subtitle = "€\(sub.price) due in \(sub.daysBefore) day(s)"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: sub.nextpayment).day
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: sub.id, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)
    }
    
    center.getNotificationSettings { settings in
        if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized{
            addRequest()
        }
        else{
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                if success{
                    addRequest()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you observing the notification from the notification center?. Post the bare minimum code

Comment: This is the code i currently have. I will put it in the main post

Comment: Instead of `center.add(request)` replace it with `center.add(request) { error in  // do what ever you want here}` The closure would be called after receiving the notification. Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter